# How to skip few enrties in a regular interval in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a data file `name.txt` with the following elements:

```
object 1
num 2
24
56
67
object 3
num 4
34
56
78
num 5
count 4
69
78
56
```

I want to remove the text lines and make a 3*3 matrix. Can anyone help me with the python code. I want to run the code for 100 events.

I tried the following:

`import itertools

 from itertools import islice
 with open('name.txt') as fp:
    for line in itertools.islice(fp, 2, None): 
        print line`

I can only skip first two lines which are strings but I want to skip all the text lines and make a 3*3 matrix.

Comment: What have you tried, and what problems did you encounter?

Comment: I tried the following which are in the next comment.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to keep only the lines you want is to use [itertools.compress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress) to filter them. As the pattern of lines to drop/keep is regular, we can generate it with [itertools.repeat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat)

So, one way to generate your matrix would be:

```
from itertools import chain, repeat, compress

lines_filter = chain.from_iterable(repeat([False]*2 + [True]*3, 3))
# will repeat 3 times the sequence 2 x False, 3 x True,

matrix = [[0]*3 for i in range(3)]

with open('test.txt') as f:
    lines = compress(f, lines_filter)
    values = map(lambda line: int(line.strip()), lines)  # or float

    # Your question doesn't make clear if the values are given by line 
    # or column. I assume by line, swap i and j otherwise.
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            matrix[i][j] = next(values)

print(matrix)
# [[24, 56, 67], [34, 56, 78], [69, 78, 56]]
```

We could also create the matrix using `itertools` - it might be harder to read, though:

```
from itertools import chain, repeat, compress

lines_filter = chain.from_iterable(repeat([False]*2 + [True]*3, 3))
# will repeat 3 times the sequence 2 x False, 3 x True

with open('test.txt') as f:
    lines = compress(f, lines_filter)
    values = map(lambda line: int(line.strip()), lines)  # or float
    line_items = [iter(values)]*3
    matrix = list(map(list, zip(*line_items)))

print(matrix)
# [[24, 56, 67], [34, 56, 78], [69, 78, 56]]

# and if you want it transposed:
t = list(map(list, zip(*matrix)))
print(t)
# [[24, 34, 69], [56, 56, 78], [67, 78, 56]]
```

Or, shorter and nicer, using `islice`:

```
from itertools import chain, repeat, compress, islice

lines_filter = chain.from_iterable(repeat([False]*2 + [True]*3, 3))
# will repeat 3 times the sequence 2 x False, 3 x True

with open('test.txt') as f:
    lines = compress(f, lines_filter)
    values = map(lambda line: int(line.strip()), lines)  # or float
    matrix = [list(islice(values, 3)) for i in range(3)] 

print(matrix)
# [[24, 56, 67], [34, 56, 78], [69, 78, 56]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged your question with `numpy`, I thought an answer using `numpy` may be useful. You can try the following:

```
import numpy as np
t = np.genfromtxt('name.txt', usecols=0)
m = t[np.isfinite(t)].reshape((3, 3))
```

Then, for your particular example:

```
In [44]: import numpy as np
    ...: t = np.genfromtxt('name.txt', usecols=0)
    ...: m = t[np.isfinite(t)].reshape((3, 3))
    ...: print(m)
    ...: 
[[ 24.  56.  67.]
 [ 34.  56.  78.]
 [ 69.  78.  56.]]
```